# What is the reason for the ark opening & closing procedure during Aleinu in High Holiday Musaph?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, musaf, ark-aron-kodesh, aleinu-leshabeiach, high-holidays

The Art Scroll & Birnbaum siddurim Nusach Ashkenaz for both Rosh Hashannah & Yom Kippur state this ark / opening procedure during the cantor's recital of the *Aleinu* prayer during Musaph on these 2 holidays:

- Ark is opened at start of the prayer
- Ark is closed during recital of the phrase שלא שם חלקינו כהם - *That he did not place our portion among theirs...* (and for those that say it, שהם משתחוים *That they bow down...")
- Ark is reopened at ואנחנו כורעים *And we bow down*

What is the reason for the multiple opening / closing, or why is the ark closed during the 1 or 2 sentences mentioned above?